# Visitor location from facebook profile

Tags: facebook, geolocation

I want to know which city a visitor of my web page comes from in the following way:

```
    1. If the visitor has a public Facebook profile,
       then return her Facebook location.
    2. Otherwise, return her location based on the IP address.
```

I know how to do (2). But is there a way to do (1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having them authorise your application, no.

Otherwise, a basic call to `/USER_ID` in the API will return their locale

Answer (score 0):

Just question the Graph API for user.location – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Answer (score 0):

You can use MaxMind API to get user's location based on his IP 
http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location

And to get user's location from his profile you can use Graph API https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/